# How to save a project in pycharm and where to find them

Tags: python, pycharm

*emphasized text*Pls help me.How can i save my project in pycharm and where will i find it.**strong text**

Comment: The question doesn't provide any detailed context

Comment: if its a folder on disk ... just open it through the file > open menu (I dont think opening it with the command line works quite right) ... it is now a pycharm project just by opening it... it is saved whereever it was ... if its a new project then select file > new > project and tell it where to save

Comment: pls explain it more clearly

Comment: i tried it and i am geting this error (Cannot modify a read-only directory 'D:\'.)

Comment: pls help i need it urgently

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @Kriti some operating systems don't allow writing to the root `D:\ ` you have to create a directory on the disk and write to it.

Answer (score 0):

The directory which PyCharm is showing the error is where you file might be.
or the directory you selected to make the project in.

Comment: Or you can make a new project to the file you want to save your code and copy the code of the file you DONOT Want